# What are my options for listening to Audiobooks?

Tags: functionality

I have a small collection of Audiobooks as MP3 files. What are my options to play these on a Windows Phone 7 device that

- Works under the lock screen
- Remembers the position I left off
- Does not drain the battery quickly
- Optimally works in the background, so that I can surf while listening.

Comment: It does not mention every feature you want perhaps maybe help. It is [Audible](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/apps/bdc813dd-c20b-41f8-8646-de72fa0b365d)

Comment: have you tried [Audible](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/apps/bdc813dd-c20b-41f8-8646-de72fa0b365d)?

Comment: Can audible play mp3 files that I already have in my collection? I was under the impression that it only played audible's portfolio.

Comment: I don't see a way it can. I have found some apps that might work, but I don't think it play under the lock screen. I'll post an answer in a bit that has a link to it

Answer (score 4):

The best option I've found so far is to abuse the Podcast feature of WP7, together with a third party tool to create RSS feeds from files in a folder.

**Advantages:**

- Does not drain battery as much as the audio book apps I've encountered.
- Uses the built in Zune controls (Volume keys / Playback buttons on the lock screen)

**Disadvantages:**

- When my device shuts down due to low battery or me wearing it in my pocket, the current position often is lost
- Filling the device with new audio books is not as streamlined as with my iPod.

(Found as in I've written such a tool. If you're interested, see https://bitbucket.org/ngollon/feeder.wp7/downloads)

Answer (score 1):

[Audio Reader](http://windowsphone.com/s?appid=32e48559-0234-e011-854c-00237de2db9e) might work for you. It is $1.29, but has a full trial mode with ads. As far as I can tell, it meets every one of your asks *except* running under lock screen. Well, I don't see it called out in the description and I can't test it now so maybe it does. :)

Anyway, give it a try and let us know how it work for you.

Comment: That looks nice! I'll test it a little, then edit your answer with Pros/Cons, with your permission.

Comment: This works well! It uses the built in audio controls, too. Runs under the lock screen and even in the background! I could make it forget its current position by pulling power, though. A good alternative to the RSS based approach, but since loading books onto it is just as complicated, no real winner. Thanks for the suggestion! =)

Comment: It looks like this one too requires uploading and _then_ downloading from a web server unnecessarily, is this the case?

Comment: Ok, scratch that, it's about having a local web server apparently. But I'm still unable to use it - a local server is successfully set up using the WP7 Helper program, the IP:port is accessible from the same laptop, but if I try to access it from the phone the page doesn't load at all.
It's a Lumia 800 connected to the same WiFi network, I've tried both having it connected via USB to the laptop and not, doesn't seem to make any difference. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

It has been really hard to set it up with Windows Phone 8. The release of the new Desktop App has at least made it possible. I posted a complete write up that explains how to do this on my blog: http://www.warrenhenke.com/uncategorized/how-to-listen-to-audiobooks-on-windows-phone-8-using-the-podcast-player

Answer (score 0):

Since the question there is time left. But if you search now a full featured AudioBook player app for Windows Phone check this:

[App in Phone Store](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=fc5528b2-1cbc-42c3-9b9a-7b5cb3815165)

Audiobook Player enables you to play audio books on your Windows Phone.
The App is optimized to play many small audio files in one folder and saving the playback position of all your book.
Audiobooks can be played from your local device, just copy your files via USB on it, and from SD-Cards.

This app is also available for Windows 8.

Comment: The app store listing only states that it is for Windows Phone 8.1 only?

Answer (score 0):

ELAudioBooks - supports mp3, m4b, wma, saves position, can change playback speed... 
Give it a try
http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=8a2e6128-630e-433c-81f7-aad07f74db08

Answer (score 0):

For me the best app for folder playlist on Windows 10 and Windows 10 Mobile is [Media Store](https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9nqbh9bw9jpx). It is a directory music and video player. I use directory as playlist.

From description:

> Put music file in the root of directory:
>   Apple [Directory]
>   - Banana [File1]
>   - Peache [File2]
>   - Lemon [File3]
>
> You will get
>
> Apple [Playlist]
>   - Banana [Song 1]
>   - Peache [Song 2]
>   - Lemon [Song 3]